# Integration of Page builder plugin with wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a word press theme. For that I need a page builder integrated with that theme,
means while installing the theme the page builder will also install in the system. and that page builder needs to show with the theme, not in plugins.can we achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

add your page builder script in a subdir of your theme for example `wp-contents/themes/vendor/pagebuilder`. Call the page builder script / plugin from your functions.php `require dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/pagebuilder/pagebuilder.php';`